# Windows 10 Compressing Memory When Not Needed

Tags: windows, windows-10

I see a lot of posts regarding people asking how to turn off memory compression, whether paging is a good idea etc, with the consensus reply always being that "Windows 10 knows best" and won't compress memory unless it needs to.

I bought a new laptop with 32gigs of ram, and I'd be willing to sign an affidavit in a court of law that the usage has never, ***ever*** gone above 19GB of ram, and only then whilst playing a game with a machine learning process training in the background.

Nevertheless, my "in use" and compressed memory right now is 15.GB (2.5GB compressed). Why is Windows compressing memory when it doesn't need to?
 Multitasking is still fast, however when I resume some old open applications, it sometimes still takes a few seconds for them to become responsive.

I realize, based on prior discussions, that disabling memory compression, paging etc will most likely not fix this problem and will instead make the system unstable. I realize also that a lot of professionals actually believe that Windows 10 will only compress or page memory when it needs to.

I speak from experience that this is not true. Windows is compressing/paging memory when it does not need to, and when it has never, since its installation, reached close to its maximum capacity.

With this in mind, given infinite ram, is there any way to disable the delay when alt-tabbing to old processes that were never shut? To me this is a fundamental design flaw if there is no way to disable this delay, whatever the cause, if the user were in theory to have an infinite amount of ram, and Windows 10 would nevertheless compress ram anyway.

Comment: you have hidden memory leak (modified memory) that is why compression runs.

Comment: @Ramhound if compressing the ram isn't about the ram usage, what is it about?

Comment: @magicandre1981 if I had a leak, shouldn't I see the ram going over 20GB, closer to 32GB? This doesn't happen, max usage ever has been 19GB.

Comment: open cmd.exe as admin, run **wpr.exe -start CPU -start ReferenceSet -filemode && timeout 10 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighMemoryUsage.etl**, zip the ETL, share it and I can see what happens